# Eclipse can't execute jdk1.7.0/bin/java, error=13, permission denied

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven-plugin, eclipse-juno

I have a maven web app project in Eclipse Juno, when I execute the project with `Goals: clean install tomcat:run`, an error prompt:

```
Exception occurred executing command line.

Cannot run program "/home/huahsin68/tool/jdk1.7.0/bin/java" (in directory "/home/huahsin68/workspace/web1"): error=13, Permission denied
```

I have tested on a console application, and it is working fine. Any idea with this?

**UPDATE on 21st Mar 2013**

I wasn't sure this happen on other platform but I'm sure I was in Fedora 17.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied

Check the permissions of the file path through the cmd line. Your Tomcat doesn't have permissions to access the directory containing the files. You will need to change those permissions.

How you do this depends on what OS you are using.

Comment: I am not sure what cause this problem, but I have abandon JDK 1.7 and switch back to JDK 1.6.